# select all conversations and last message of each conversation (+ user data)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables

table: **users**

```
user_id | username
------------------
1       | john
2       | jane
3       | jack
```

table: **conversations**

```
conversation_id | sender_id | receiver_id
-----------------------------------------
1               | 1         | 2
2               | 1         | 3
```

table: **messages**

```
message_id | conversation_id | user_id | message         | timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 1               | 1       | hi jane         | 12345
2          | 1               | 2       | hi john         | 12345
3          | 1               | 1       | how are you?    | 12345
4          | 1               | 2       | i'm fine!       | 12345
5          | 1               | 1       | i'm okay too!   | 12345
```

What I want to achieve, in one query if possible: fetching all the conversations where a specific user (let's say user ID: 1) is the sender OR receiver, and the latest message of that conversation.

First query: I'm selecting all conversation_id's where user ID = 1 is the sender or receiver, and I'm fetching the **other** user ID as 'user_id' in the results:

```
SELECT c.conversation_id,
CASE
    WHEN
        c.sender_id = 1
    THEN
        c.receiver_id
    ELSE
        c.sender_id
END as user_id
FROM conversations AS c
```

I also want the username of the OTHER user in the conversation. I can do this with this query:

```
SELECT c.conversation_id, u.username,
CASE
    WHEN
        c.sender_id = 1
    THEN
        c.receiver_id
    ELSE
        c.sender_id
END as user_id
FROM conversations AS c
JOIN users AS u ON
CASE
    WHEN
        c.sender_id = 1
    THEN
        c.receiver_id = u.user_id
    ELSE
        c.sender_id = u.user_id
END
```

This also works! But now I'm stuck. In the same query, I also want the **last message in every conversation**. In my example, there is a conversation between user ID's 1 and 2. It doesn't matter if the last message is from the sender or the receiver, I just want the last message AND timestamp.

How can I achieve this? I'm trying with MAX(), GROUP BY, ... but I'm getting really stuck.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `join` and `distinct on` do what you want:

```
select distinct on (c.conversation_id) c.*, m.*
from conversations c join
     messages m
     on m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
where 1 in (c.sender_id, c.receiver_id)
order by c.conversation_id, m.id desc;
```

I don't know if you prefer ordering by messages or by ids.

The above query *select*s the records.  If you then want to order them by conversations . . . you can use a subquery:

```
select cm.*
from (select distinct on (c.conversation_id) c.*, m.*  -- list out the columns you want here so there are no duplicates
      from conversations c join
           messages m
           on m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
      where 1 in (c.sender_id, c.receiver_id)
      order by c.conversation_id, m.id desc
     ) cm
order by m.id desc
```

Comment: I order on the ID of the last message, so conversations with new messages will appear at the top

Comment: I want to sort on the ID of the last message, now it's sorting on the conversation ID. When I add a message to conversation 2, conversation 2 has to be fetched first.